# how to add element after new HTML tag by Jquery automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, loops

**Note:**  *I wanted to use JQuery but It was solved by wordpress loop and php.*

I  am working with WordPress and I created a new part to display the last news to my users. News exists between `li` tags but the issue is when a new `li` tag is added, I want to add a `span` tag after the last `li` but I do not know how to do that.

I know it is possible with jQuery. Note that `li` tags will be added **automatically** (by the WordPress loop for posts) not manually, so I need a **loop and if** in Jquery to count `li` tags at first, then when a new `li` tag was added, add a `span` tags to that new `li` tag automatically.

My code:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li id="one">title one</li>
    <li id="two">title two</li>
    <li id="three">title three</li>
</ul>
```

I need to add a `span` tag like this:

```
<li id="four">title four<span>new</span></li>
```

## UPDATE 1:

the loop for getting posts title from wordpress:

```
<ul>
    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?> <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>

    <?php endwhile; ?><?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: well that would be invalid HTML, span would need to be in the li

Comment: Adding anything after a closing `</li>` other than either `<li>`, `</ol>`, or `</ul>` is invalid HTML

Comment: Aside the bad markup comments, is there a reason you don't just do this in the wp template?

Comment: @epascarello @j08691 @Kai Qing  I changed the code but i mean: consider those `li` tags will be added by a CMs (like wordpress) and i want to count the `li` tags and when another `li` is added to them, one `span` tag will be added to just that new `li` and this action will be repeated (in a loop by JQuery) unless the user clack on the `li` tag and the `span` tag will be disappeared. did you get my mean?

Comment: is it compulsory to use jquery to check for last <li> tag? If you are using while loop or for loop you can specify a condition that if the <li> element is last element add a <span> element with it. Can you show the code where loop is actually working to help you better. As there are plenty of methods but I want to provide optimal solution.

Comment: WordPress generates content from server, it is better to add span tag while content is getting generated by loop rather than adding it with jQuery after receiving on client browser.

Comment: @Codesigner i could not understand your mean. would you explain with an example codes. i added the loop in above

Comment: @sagar  i know i can get the last `li` by JQuery but i want to add `span` tag when a new `li` tag is added automatically  by wordpress loop. did you get my mean? i added the loop above in question

Comment: @tikebartar, is any data you have regarding the post is read or not while adding post to li tag?. Because we can get last li using jquery as told by Kevin Whinnery, but we need read status of post.

Comment: in laravel there is way 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: @Thamarai T my friend, exactly i want to add `span` tag to those post has not been read and i do not have any idea about that you mean to realize those post. can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this directly through wordpress

```
<ul>

<?php if(have_posts()) : ?> <?php 

global $wp_query;
$totalPosts = $wp_query->post_count; //count the total posts
$count = 1;
while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 
if($count < $totalPosts){ ?>
    <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
<?php }
else{ ?>
    <li><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></li>
<?php 
}
$count++;
endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot my friend. but this code add `span` tag to the last title or all titles when `$count >= $totalPosts`?

Comment: only the latest post will get the span tag.

Comment: thanks thanks thanks. but another question i need your help. how can understand that the user has been read the post?

Comment: I can only provide pseudo implementation check here: https://pastebin.com/raw/cLnQ4pVK

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider adding the `span` inside the `li` tag. Use the :last-child CSS selector to get a handle to the last item in the list, then append your desired HTML. [Here is an example using jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzmn5s49/), per your request.

```js
var newHtml = '<span style="color:red;">new</span>';
$('#list li:last-child').append(newHtml);
```

Comment: thanks a lot my friend for helping but i mean: consider those `li` tags will be added by a CMs (like wordpress) and i want to count the `li` tags and when another `li` is added to them, one `span` tag will be added to just that new `li` and this action will be repeated (in a loop by JQuery) unless the user clack on the `li` tag and the `span` tag will be disappeared. did you get my mean?

Comment: so among all news tag, the last one only need to have span tag, right?

Comment: If you are about to add "new" tag to post which is received by Ajax call then add your logic in ajax call.

Comment: @Thamarai T yes. among all news tag, the last one only need to have span tag, when a new `li` was added

Comment: @Codesigner i do not knoe how to do that with Ajax, can you help me by example and code? thanks

Comment: I am considering that your new post append with ajax call not with browser refresh.
If it's append on browser refresh then you must have to set your logic in server side script, may be with wordpress function or core PHP (I am not wordpress developer).
I will try to give example early as possible if post append with ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use this by getting the post date

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?> <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php
        $datetime = strtotime( get_the_date() );
            $yesterday = strtotime("-1 days");
            if ( $datetime >= $yesterday ) {
            $new = '<span>New</span>';
            } else {
                $new = '';
            }
        ?>
    <li><?php the_title(); ?> <?php echo $new ?> </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot my friend for answering but i want to add `span` tag when a new post is published. the point is that `span` tag in not based on time. when a new post is published, a `span` tag will be added to its title and will be appeared until user click on it and then will be disappeared. did you get my mind?

Comment: then you can use a custom table where you can store post id user id or IP address and when a user clicks on a post save it in DB.

Comment: i do not know as detail. would you explain more and with code? i know how to create a table but what about save that as post meta?